# ionic cordova run android --device successful but app not showing on phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

The command was working, then I uninstalled the app on my phone and ran the command again. It says it's successful, but the app doesn't re-appear in the app drawer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your device connected, run `adb uninstall io.ionic.starter` (or whatever your package name is, it should appear in terminal after a successful run android), then reinstall with `adb install -r PATH_TO_APK` (also appears in terminal, under "Built the following apk(s):")

Comment: Its is weird that although the app may not show up in the apps list it may still be installed and `adb uninstall your.package.name` solves the problem, as you suggested.

Comment: Praise the lord.